# Display Unclaimed in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, drivers, graphics

I am having an issue with booting up ubuntu out of nowhere. It gets stuck at purple screen and doesn't present login screen.

While in recovery mode it works. Many people suggested this to be the issue with graphics drivers. Which also seems to be.

I tried `lshw -c display` which show display unclaimed. This is the output.

[image: Screenshot- Display Unclaimed]

My system has somehow started using `Galium 0.4 on llvmpipe` graphics.

What are the possible solutions for getting my ubuntu work with normal boot ? And how to fix this graphics drivers issue ?

Comment: I might be facing the same problem. I am having issues while playing videos while in rescue mode. Yes, it's definitely a graphics problem but I haven't found the solution yet. My system does not have dedicated graphics; only intel graphics.